# Kotlin Flow: Testing hangs

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow, kotlin-coroutines, kotest

I am trying to test Kotlin implementation using Flows. I use Kotest for testing. This code works:

ViewModel:

```
val detectedFlow = flow<String> {
    emit("123")
    delay(10L)
    emit("123")
}
```

Test:

```
class ScanViewModelTest : StringSpec({
    "when the flow contains values they are emitted" {
        val detectedString = "123"
        val vm = ScanViewModel()
        launch {
            vm.detectedFlow.collect {
                it shouldBe detectedString
            }
        }
    }
})
```

However, in the real ViewModel I need to add values to the flow, so I use `ConflatedBroadcastChannel` as follows:

```
private val _detectedValues = ConflatedBroadcastChannel<String>()
val detectedFlow = _detectedValues.asFlow()

suspend fun sendDetectedValue(detectedString: String) {
    _detectedValues.send(detectedString)
}
```

Then in the test I try:

```
"when the flow contains values they are emitted" {
    val detectedString = "123"
    val vm = ScanViewModel()
    runBlocking {
        vm.sendDetectedValue(detectedString)
    }
    runBlocking {
        vm.detectedFlow.collect { it shouldBe detectedString }
    }
}
```

The test just hangs and never completes. I tried all kind of things: `launch` or `runBlockingTest` instead of `runBlocking`, putting sending and collecting in the same or separate coroutines, `offer` instead of `send`... Nothing seems to fix it. What am I doing wrong?

Update: If I create flow manually it works:

```
private val _detectedValues = ConflatedBroadcastChannel<String>()
val detectedFlow =  flow {
    this.emit(_detectedValues.openSubscription().receive())
}
```

So, is it a bug in `asFlow()` method?

Comment: did you tried launching on other dispatchers, just for debugging purposes?

Comment: yes i did. no effect. btw, I tried newly released StateFlow/MutableStateFlow and the issue persists

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that the [collect](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/collect.html) function you used in your test is a suspend function that will suspend the execution until the `Flow` is finished.

In the first example, your `detectedFlow` is finite. It will just emit two values and finish. In your question update, you are also creating a finite flow, that will emit a single value and finish. That is why your test works.

However, in the second (real-life) example the flow is created from a `ConflatedBroadcastChannel` **that is never closed**. Therefore the `collect` function suspends the execution forever. To make the test work without blocking the thread forever, you need to make the flow finite too. I usually use the `first()` operator for this. Another option is to `close` the `ConflatedBroadcastChannel` but this usually means modifications to your code just because of the test which is not a good practice.

This is how your test would work with the `first()` operator

```
"when the flow contains values they are emitted" {
    val detectedString = "123"
    val vm = ScanViewModel()
    runBlocking {
        vm.sendDetectedValue(detectedString)
    }
    runBlocking {
        vm.detectedFlow.first() shouldBe detectedString
    }
}
```

Comment: What if our entire test function is marked as `runBlocking`?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky I believe entire test function would also hang in that case. How do we handle such cases where production code uses `collect` on flow and channels?

Comment: @TomášHavlíček `collect` doesn't hang, as it is asynchronous

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Collect suspends until flow ends